# Godoc: Limit Documentation to Project (Not Dependencies)

Tags: go, documentation, documentation-generation, godoc

I'm trying to use Godoc to generate some basic documentation for a project, but every time I do that, it adds documentation for all the Go packages as well. Is there a way to control this and have it only generate documentation for my project code?

I'm using:

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

Comment: As you can see from `godoc --help`, you cannot restrict it to specific packages. It doesn't really hurt anything to cover all packages though - is there a specific reason you're trying to restrict it?

Comment: It's including docs for the entire Go library which doesn't make sense. There's no reason to include that in the output. It's just distracting at best.

Comment: Distracting how? Just go to the documentation you actually need. It's not as if it renders all the package docs on one page, you don't have to look at any docs you don't want to see. It doesn't seem like there is any downside to generating "extra" docs.

Comment: I agree, the documentation is heavily weighted down to include all the standard go packages and external dependency documentation, those are available online anyway.  I don't see the need to have this information duplicated on every project level godoc instance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to control this and have it only generate documentation for my project code?

No.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation generation tools besides Godoc that can accomplish this?

Comment: @Brandon: "Are you aware of any documentation generation tools besides Godoc that can accomplish this?" No.

Comment: That's why people saying stack overflow is toxic, THE answer is “No.”